# Как вызвать функцию, которая хранится строкой

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть, например, функция в виде строки `let a  = "function() {return {a: b, c: d, e: f};}";`, если попытаться написать `a()` - `a is not a function`; через `eval(a)` - `Function statements require a function name`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011280/3129992

Comment: `eval(\`(${a})()\`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let a  = "function() {return {a: 0, c: 0, e: 0};}";
const f = (0,eval)(`(${a})`)
console.log(f());
```

Answer (score -1):

Либо eval(), либо так:

```
new Function('return '+a)();
```

Но вообще eval не рекомендуют использовать.

Comment: `eval` не работает же, написали)

Comment: не знаю у меня по всякому работает: eval('test='+a)(). Единственное не понятно какая цель преследуется.

Comment: в ответе `eval(a)`, а в комментарии `eval('test=' + a)` - это разные вещи

Comment: метод один и тот же, зависит от того что внутри "a" находится, так и нужно подстраивать eval, я так понял там все что угодно может быть...